# Isolate the variable in an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to isolate the variable x for the equation

$x^{4}+x^{2}-9=y$

all I can think of is doing the following

$x^{2}(x^{2}+1)=y+9$

but then I have no idea how to proceed

Comment: Are you looking to solve for $x$? In that case, use the quadratic formula to find $x^2$, then take square roots.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ u=x^2 $ and then work with the equation $ y=u^2 + u -9  $. If you want to find the roots then use the quadratic equation and then convert your answer back in terms of $x$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use $u = x^2$ and reduce the equation from a quartic one to a quadratic and use quadratic formula.